# Connecting android studio project to Parse without Parse SDK file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new

I am able to connect an application to parse by following the instructions on the parse website. But when I download the sdk and open it, the apps MainActivity is an "Empty Activity". I want my app to have a different activity for the MainActivity. Also, if I use the Parse sdk file, I am unable to use some of the activities in my project. Eg. I cannot use a blank activity. But if I don't use the parse sdk file [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jj42.png), I cannot connect to the server. Copying and pasting the code in the MainActivity doesn't work. The program doesn't recognize any of the Parse code. Eg. Parse Object, ParseUser, etc. Also, since I can't create a new project and use Parse, I can't add my company name into the project.

On the Parse website it says I can compile everything myself, 
http"s"://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-sdk-android
(remove "" in url)
I think that's what I need to fix my problem, but I have no idea what to do. Any help would be appreciated.​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I cannot connect to the server.*

You are enable to connect the server by initing with correct appId, clientKey, serverUrl on "Application" a specified in manifest.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
        .applicationId("myID")
                .clientKey("myKey")
               // .server("http://localhost:1337/parse")
.build()
);
```

*Copying and pasting the code in the MainActivity doesn't work.*

MainActiviy is useless, the basic function is work by permissions in manifest, lib from build.gradle and init in application.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jj42.png Android studio doesn't recognize the Parse code. If the permissions have to be in the manifest, lib, and init in application, then they aren't there. How do I add them and what do I add?

Comment: check you have these 2 in app/build.gradle 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}

Comment: and you must use sync project to get lib from remote(click the button or find it from Tools->Android->SyncProject)